# To fix a csv file so sql server can import the file

Tags: sql-server, import, ssis, formatting

I have a csv file which is comma delimited but it has some address field with commas in them and a description field which starts and ends with double quotes and has commas within it.
Import wizrad of sql server just adds in extra columns and therefore errors on the data type for other fields which this data is extending into.
If I use excel the field is correctly seen and I can therefore import it but I want to automate this import so dont want to have to open each file (of which I have thousands )into in excel.

I have tried powershell

```
DECLARE @file NVARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @cmd  NVARCHAR(255); 
SET @file='C:\path\filename' 
SET @cmd = 'powershell "Import-csv -path '+@file+'.csv -Delimiter '','' | Export-CSV -path '+@file+'_converted.csv -Delimiter ''|'' -NoType " '
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell
```

but get the error

```
   output
   Import-Csv : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
   'Premium'.
   At line:1 char:1
    + Import-csv -path C:\DWfilestoload\Collect Premium Insolvency Output.csv 
     -Delimit ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        ~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Csv], ParameterBind 
    ingException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell 
   .Commands.ImportCsvCommand

    NULL
```

Any other ideas to get this file in a good format for import or to swap the delimiter, I have tried replacing the , for a | but its the same effect.

Comment: Generate the file using FixedWidth or RaggedRight option instead of delimeted one.

Comment: As whoever is generating the file for you to generate with `|` pipe delimited or a format you can use. If not then how do you currently determine start of address with comma and the end of the address?

Comment: I would highly recommend punching the person who produces this file directly in the face.

Comment: Yeah I thought that.The data has stuff like sdfds,sdfdsf,"sdf,sdfd,",dfd,dfd.dfd, so import wizard will delimit at each comma Excel will accept the " and not delimit the commas therafter. I think I need to look at writing some sort of batch script to clean this up as I need to automate it.

Comment: Ragged right did not work, the file is sent to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a text qualifier so that the data values are surrounded by quotes, for example.  Or come up with a more complex delimiter like |~ or some combination like would be very uncommon.

Comment: Do you think If I can add an extra delimeter like " or |, it will put the data as it should be.The data looks like this example asdf,asdf,"asdfd,afd,adf",dfd.....

Comment: Text qualifiers are easier to troubleshoot because you can open the file and see it more clearly, it would looks like this:  "asdf,asdf","asdfd,afd,adf","dfd".  Pipe is also a good choice for some datasets, try it out.

Comment: I found a the text qualifier option in the ssis import wizard, Once I ticked it, the whole of the column that had double quotes came in properly.